# How to calculate the same numbers with their frequency distributions

Tags: r

Here is my data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20), 
                B = c(60,50,60,40,50,20,20,30,20,60,60,30,20,30,40,20,30,20,30,60))
```

I want to calculate the sum of similar values in B and then multiply them by their frequency distributions (for example, 20 observed 6 times. So 20*6= 120). So I would have these values:

120, 150, 80, 100, 300.

Then I want to sum these values and then divide it by the sample (120+150+80+100+300)/20. So I would get this number 37.5. Is there a  R  code.  Thank for your help.

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(x)[,.N *B ,B][, sum(V1)/B]`

Comment: Akrun@ does  not work

Comment: is there a specific code in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is more elegant solution bus by using table functionality you can do something like this:

```
sum(as.numeric(names(table(x$B))) * table(x$B)) / nrow(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
tbl_df(x) %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  summarise(count=n()) %>% 
  mutate(c=B*count)%>%
  summarise(result=sum(c)/sum(count))
```

Output

```
Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

  result
   (dbl)
1   37.5
```

Comment: Dambo @Sorry, does not work. Have you tested it yourself?

Comment: @user1309 Sorry, I forgot to average the result. Now it should work, I have added the output too.